# how to Send Notification using flow with the group

Tags: visual-workflow, process-builder, administration

I'm trying to figure out how to setup send notification using the FLOW and I know how to configure but I have read and seen lots of youtube video talks about sending to the owner of the record, but what I want to do is to:

1. how can you send notification to number of users
2. how to leverage groups, say if I create a group and I can add few users to the group

but I have not found any resources that talks about the above two criteria.

I have seen the in Process Builder you have options to choose the group and you define the group name but why can not have the similar in Flow ? unless I'm not looking at the right place.

Any help?

EDIT:

Here is what I was trying to do, please see the screen shot

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is what I did:

#### Prep Work

As @Willian-Matheus suggested, I created a Text Collection Variable:

[image]

---

## Flow

[image]

#### Step 1

I don't know how you did it - there may be a better way. But for this example I used a **Get Records** to grab the ID for an existing Custom Notification Type.

#### Step 2

You need to change your **Get Records** element to get *Group **Member*** records, and use whatever means you need to in the Condition Field and Value to find your *Group*. *(For quickness I "hard-coded" a Group Id.)*:

[image]

#### Step 3

Loop through the records retrieved from **Step 2**.

#### Step 4

Add the `CollaborationGroupMember.Member.Id` value to the Collection Variable:

[image]

#### Step 5

Send the Notification using the Text Collection Variable in the `Recipient IDs`:

[image]

---

### Result

I got this:

[image]

And when I logged in as one of the group members, they got this:

[image]

Comment: 1+ Thanks for make this screen shot and super helpful but I lost in step 2,3,4 can you please add some detail, in step 3 you said `Loop through the Group Member records` how would I do? and in step 2 you not using Group Member

Comment: _"A picture is worth 1000 words."_ I made a few edits that will hopefully clarify: In **Step 2** I meant that you should get _Group Member_ records - in your screenshot you are getting _Group_ records. Use the Condition Requirements to find your _Group_, and specify to store All Records so the Get Records element will grab all Group Members of your Group. || I changed the wording of **Step 3** to hopefully be clearer. || That's all there is to **Step 4** - I don't see what I can add or how I can elaborate that one.

Comment: I'm stuck in step 4 and I see from the screen shot you have selected `The "For_Each_Group_Member.Member.Id` but I'm getting error when I try to `resource can't be used as a merge field.`

Comment: Are you available to [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/128968/discussion-between-nick-kahn-and-moonpie?tab=general) about this?

Comment: @NickKahn : I added more info in the chat.

Comment: @NickKahn : I think the final puzzle piece can be found in the chat.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to send a custom notification to many users in flow, create a variable resource with type String collection, and add in the list the users or public groups ids desired.

When you send the notification, bind this resource variable in the recipients [image]

Comment: I will post in my question the error that I'm getting when try to bind.

Comment: @willian-matheus : I think your answer is correct, you just need to explain it clearer. Maybe in a sandbox or Trailhead Playground org, you could mock up what you are talking about in a Flow and add a screenshot of that to your answer.